# Calling a dataset and table related to it using parameter in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset

I have 3 different datasets and each having a different table and a parameter which is having 3 values, for  each value it has to call one dataset and as well as the related table to that dataset what can be done to make it possible.

Comment: A quick apprach would be create three tables each with its dataset, then just hide all tables except that table selected in your parameter. You can do that using the Visibility property in SSRS Tablix components.

Comment: I also done that but it is always taking the first dataset results...i will explain you more detailed..... i have 3 queries.. so i have created a dataset.. i selected query type as text.. and created 3 parameters file_type, startdate and enddate...by using if , else if and else loop i build the query  and refreshed the fields..but it is taking only first query columns only(which is having more columns than compared to other 2 queries) and regardless of the parameter i declared it is executing the first query i given in the loop and i also created 3 tables for each dataset but not use